# Spinup a VM from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, virtual-machine, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

As part of the build process in Jenkins, i need to launch a VM, do some testing on it and shutdown the VM. I would want to provision this VM at run time and destroy afterwards. is this possible?

Comment: Using the [vSphere plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/vsphere-cloud) (and admin privileges) you can do that. If you want to create a new VM you can either clone one or create one from a template.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do so completely out of jenkins without relying on 3rd party VM environment? For ex spin-up ec2 instance ( based of vm )?

Comment: Right, I should have asked you what virtualization environment you had. To be frank, I don't know as I have no experience with Amazon. If you type `ec2` in the [plugin page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/) you will get a few plugins.